# IPv6 conflict on same network

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, embedded-linux

My requirement is, i am trying create a graphical user interface for my embedded system for ipv6.So i have option for setting manual IPv6 address.My requirement is when i enter manual IPV6 address,i need to check that particular address is all ready assigned to any machine in the same subnet.How we can check that in Linux based systems .Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Why are link-local addresses not good enough?

Comment: Otherwise you could scan the subnet with nmap as stated here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12826/which-tool-apart-from-nmap-can-i-use-to-scan-a-range-of-ipv6-addresses

Comment: what about unique local

Comment: how to use namp for discover all ipV6 address in subnet

Comment: Using nmap is silly. You already _know_ the address – why would you spend years scanning the whole /64 subnet if you only need to check the same address that the user just entered?

Answer (score 4):

Don't invent your own methods – IPv6 specifies "Duplicate Address Detection" in [RFC 4862](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4862), based on sending Neighbour Solicitations to see if another host responds.

> #### 5.4.  Duplicate Address Detection
>
> Duplicate Address Detection MUST be performed on all unicast
> addresses prior to assigning them to an interface, regardless of
> whether they are obtained through stateless autoconfiguration,
> DHCPv6, or manual configuration, with the following exceptions:

Comment: DAD is applicable on Manual configration

Comment: The DAD algorithm is still _required_ for manually configured addresses as well, it doesn't matter where they came from.

Comment: I think its only for SLAAC

Comment: Um, I even specifically quoted the part of RFC 4862 that says it's required for everything.

Comment: Also look at RFC7527

Comment: But DAD it will take little more time

Comment: i am going to use ping

Comment: is tehre any command like ndp?

Comment: Why would it take more time than a ping? The OS must do exactly the same thing (neighbour lookup) when preparing to send a ping anyway.